# More RAM for minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Trying to allocate more RAM for Minecraft to run a little better. When I go to the JVM Arguments this is whats already in there:

```
-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

If I try to change anything minecraft wont start and in game it shows it only has 462MB now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument at the beginning: `-xmx1G` defines the maximum ram usage.
Try changing the `1G` to `3500M` for 3.5GB Maximum usage.
Also if that doesn't work change it to`1500M`
Also get 64-Bit Java or else the steps above might not work.

Comment: Anything other then 1G pulls up this message "Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1536000KB object heap
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release"

Comment: Figured it out! When upgraded my java it installed 32 bit instead of keeping 64 bit got it to 64 bit and it works great now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Baggiergorgon41 of course! 32 bit only allows less then 2 GB. I forgot about that

Comment: @MadMrCrazy 32bit java allows only 1GB RAM, not 2GB ;-)

Comment: @AntoineHejlík I feel stupid now...