# Minecraft Singleplayer chunk render problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Large chunks in my world are getting taken out. I've tried going in and out of the Nether, disconnecting and reconnecting, and going far away and coming back. I need a solution for my chunk loading. What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Tried installing Optifine? This is not a vanilla solution but always helps with chunks.

Comment: Do you have enough free space on your disk? Does it happen in one region of one world, whole world, or in any world? Are those just missing chunks? If yes, can you interact with them (Don't risk, if you're on survival)?

Comment: Try adding more RAM to Minecraft. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/259000/142044

Comment: Try F3+A
its refreshes your chunks

Comment: It's a known problem in MC 1.9 and is fixed in 1.9.4 (if you are on 1.9 now).

Answer (score 1):

Try to lower the render chunk distance a bit, it might work if you have the render distance too high, I have had that problem too.